# Shared Element Transition from Activity to Fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-activity, shared-element-transition

I have a simple `Activity` with an `ImageView`:

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/rl_container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/iv_picture"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:transitionName="@string/pic_viewer_transition" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

I want to share this `ImageView` to the `Fragment` in this `Activity`. Here's Fragment XML:

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@android:color/black">

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/iv_picture"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:scaleType="centerInside"
    android:transitionName="@string/pic_viewer_trasition"/>
```

Here's my code to provide Sharing:

```
iv_picture.setOnClickListener {
        val f = PictureViewer()
        val args = Bundle().apply {
            putParcelable("TESTING", picInfo)
        }
        f.arguments = args
        f.sharedElementEnterTransition = TransitionCustom()
        f.sharedElementReturnTransition = TransitionCustom()


        supportFragmentManager.beginTransaction()
            .addSharedElement(iv_picture, activity.getString(R.string.pic_viewer_transition))
            .replace(R.id.rl_container, f)
            .addToBackStack(null)
            .commit()
    }
```

But nothing happens. This code creates and shows my Fragment without any transition. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Did you ever manage to get this working?

Comment: @MichaelHanson looks like it's not gonna work this way. You can only do Activity to Activity or Fragment to Fragment transitions.